# How do I add an external array into my Rx Observable?

Tags: ios, swift, filter, observable, rx-swift

I have an `Observable` and would like it to `filter` `elements` that exists in an external `array`. The problem is that an `element` obviously can't be compared directly to an `array`, so I `loop` the `array` and then make the comparison. This doesn't work because the return statement needs to be outside of the `for` loop.

```
    func scanAndFilterCoreData() -> Observable<BleHandler.BlePeripheral> {

        let request = NSFetchRequest<LocalDoorCoreDataObject>(entityName: "LocalDoorCoreDataObject")
        let result = self.coreDataHandler.fetchAll(fetchRequest: request)

        return bleHandler.scan(serviceId: AppSettings.discoverServiceId)
            .flatMap{ Observable.from($0) }
            .filter { value in
                for coreData in result {
                    return value.peripheral.identifier.uuidString == coreData.dPeripheralId
                }
        }
    }
```

Being new to `Rx` I'm thinking there has to be some way to include the external `array` into the `Observable` as a second `parameter`, or how is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use map instead of filter:

```
.map { value in
    let uuidString = value.peripheral.identifier.uuidString
    return result.filter { $0.dPeripheralId == uuidString }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's really nice, thanks a lot for helping me out :)